# Null reference exception on data refresh in TapGestureRecognizer bound to command

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

I have a ListView, whose contents I refresh with a button click. ListView is bound to `ObservableCollection<MyClass>` in view model.
However, I get null reference exception in iOS on data refresh (but it works fine in Android).

The exception is thrown at `Main` method in iOS application.

```
// NullReferenceException thrown here.
UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");
```

The following is the stack trace.

> at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.EventTracker.LoadRecognizers () [0x0005d] in :0 
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.EventTracker.OnElementChanged (System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementChangedEventArgs e) [0x0004e] in :0 
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].OnElementChanged (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ElementChangedEventArgs`1[TElement] e) [0x0002c] in :0 
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ViewRenderer`2[TView,TNativeView].OnElementChanged (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ElementChangedEventArgs`1[TElement] e) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ImageRenderer.<>n__0 (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ElementChangedEventArgs`1[TElement] e) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ImageRenderer+d__2.MoveNext () [0x000d6] in :0 
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.2/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:152 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.b__6_0 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.2/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:1018 
>     at UIKit.UIKitSynchronizationContext+c__AnonStorey0.<>m__0 () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5665/6857dfcc/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIKitSynchronizationContext.cs:24 
>     at Foundation.NSAsyncActionDispatcher.Apply () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5665/6857dfcc/source/xamarin-macios/src/Foundation/NSAction.cs:163 
>     at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
>     at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5665/6857dfcc/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79 
>     at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00038] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5665/6857dfcc/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63 
>     at Omers.MyTeam.Mobile.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in /Users/user/Projects/proj/Company.Proj.Mobile/Company.Proj.Mobile.iOS/Main.cs:12

The following is the offending code.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding PeopleData}" HasUnevenRows="True">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid>
                    ...
                    <Image VerticalOptions="Center"
                               Source="phone_icon"
                               WidthRequest="45"
                               HeightRequest="45"
                               Margin="0,0,5,0"
                               Opacity="0.27">
                            <!--<Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" 
                                                      Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference PeoplePage}, Path=BindingContext.CallPersonCommand}"
                                                      CommandParameter="{Binding .}"></TapGestureRecognizer>
                            </Image.GestureRecognizers>-->
                        </Image>

                <Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The `TapGestureRecognizer` for the Image causes the exception if it is uncommented. The Content Page is named `PeoplePage`.

The first time ListView is populated is on application start up, without errors. 
I click a button to repopulate ListView the second time - works fine. I click a button again to refresh ListView - it errors out.

Clicking button simply refreshes data in `ObservableCollection<MyClass>` to which ListView is bound.

Any ideas on this are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: have you tried stepping through it in the debugger?

Comment: Yes. The code runs fine. And then error is thrown. I tried removing Command from TapGestureRecognizer and used blank event handler instead, but same thing happens. If I remove event handler, it runs fine. Hmm...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem as follows.

Before, when I was refreshing data in `ObservableCollection<MyClass>` I would do it similar to the following.

```
// PeopleData is ObservableCollection<MyClass>
PeopleData.Clear();
foreach (var person in retrievedFromApiPeople)
{
    PeopleData.Add(person);
}
```

Now, I added a backing field for the `PeopleData` property and simply assign a new `ObservableCollection` to the property and raise notification, similar to the following.

```
private ObservableCollection<MyClass> _peopleData;
public ObservableCollection<MyClass> PeopleData
{
    get => _peopleData;
    set
    {
        _peopleData = value;
        // INotifyPropertyChanged implementation.
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => PeopleData);
    }
}
```

And use it as follows.

```
PeopleData = retrievedFromApiPeople;
```

This approach works. Not sure why the other way wasn't working.

Comment: I am facing exactly the same issue, your workaround helps, and works. Thanks!

Comment: **EDIT**: well, solves immediate crash, but if I change the collection several times after each other, it crashes sooner or later (tried on ios simulator). What I know, it's related to the Label.TapGestureRecognizer in the list. If I remove it, no crash, even with the original scenario.

Comment: I hope you find the solution to this.. I guess it could be a bug in XF.

Answer (score 0):

Was facing the same issue, but it is solved in the latest version of Xamarin.Forms (2.5.1.444934).